# Codewars kata training. Returns None

Tags: python

Why this code return None? But print(sum_) in else, gives the correct answer

```
n = 942
```

```
def digital_root(n):
    n_str = str(n)
    result = []
    sum_ = 0
    for i in range(0, len(n_str), 1):
        result.append(int(n_str[i: i + 1]))
```

```
    for i in result:
        sum_ += i
    
    if len(str(sum_)) > 1:
        digital_root(sum_)

    else:
        return sum_
```

Comment: `if ...: ` no return `else: return sum_`

Comment: You want to learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and use an IDE on your machine, not just an online editor.

Answer (score 0):

Here when you are calling the function recursively it calculates the root correctly but it is not returning anything to the caller.

```
if len(str(sum_)) > 1:
     return  digital_root(sum_)
```

Please add the return statement and try.

Answer (score 0):

you lose return before the digital_root(sum_)
digital_root(sum_) -> return digital_root(sum_)

```
def digital_root(n):
    n_str = str(n)
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(n_str), 1):
        result.append(int(n_str[i: i + 1]))

    sum_ = sum(result)
    if len(str(sum_)) > 1:
        return digital_root(sum_)
    else:
        return sum_
```